# Find letter assigned to main drive

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a function like `Environ` to find what drive the main drive in my business has been mapped to on a particular PC.

Using the filepath "G:\Eworking\SET\Operations\file" I know that my PC has been mapped so that that filepath is within G drive but others may be mapped differently so I'd like to determine which it is.

I've tried the if else method of going through the alphabet and doing a `if Dir([filepath]) then` before (see below) but I was wondering if there's a better way of doing this?

```
Sub LoopThroughDrives()
sFilePath As String

sFilePath = ":\Eworking\SET\Operations\file"

If Dir("A" & sFilePath) > 0 Then
    msgbox ("It's in drive A")
    Else
        If Dir("B" & sFilePath) > 0 Then
            msgbox ("It's in drive B")
            Else
                If Dir("C" & sFilePath) > 0 Then
                    msgbox ("It's in drive C")
                    Else
                        '...........................
                        'All other letters of the alphabet, checking each possibility
                        '...........................
                End If
        End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198705.aspx or https://awrcorp.com/download/faq/english/scripts/basic_file_opperation.aspx for how to enumerate drives using the FileSystemObject

Comment: Is there a problem with using the UNC path?

Comment: If your code is working I'd suggest you put it up for review (all of it!) on [codereview.se] - "code works, but my eyes want to pop out" sounds very much like a very good CR post!

Comment: @Jeremy if the drive is mapped to a network path, then `d.ShareName` in my example might work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A For ... Next loop using the ASCII character seems appropriate.

```
dim c as integer
for c = 65 to 90
    If CBool(Len(Dir(Chr(c) & sFilePath))) Then
        msgbox "It's in drive " & Chr(c)   '<~~msgbox, not magbox
        exit for
    end if
next c
if c > 90 then msgbox "never found"
```

Comment: Something like this is much better than what I've had but it's skipping of (ie is not true) when it's on the drive it should accept on (drive G) and going down to "never found" message box - any ideas why?

Comment: @Jeremy - If **file** is a folder and not a file then you should be using the vbDirectory parameter  in the [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779.aspx). e.g. `If CBool(Len(Dir(Chr(c) & sFilePath, vbDirectory))) Then`

Comment: it was the file path was missing a "\" on the end so didn't recognize it as a folder (rookie mistake!) - Thanks very much for this

Answer (score 7):

you can get the drive letters and paths like this:

```
For Each d In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").Drives
    Debug.Print d.DriveLetter, d.Path, d.ShareName
Next
```

Comment: ++for a MUCH better way to iterate drives (vs iterating the alphabet)... although the loop body should perhaps *try* to use OP's `sFilePath`.

Comment: I answered before reading the question and comments. Tim's links in the comments have better examples, and I think its better to use the full mapped path instead of the mapped drive letter.